# Performance of Android activities

Tags: android, performance

Whats the performance difference between the following options

1. starting an activity and moveTaskToBack(true) on backPressed with handling onNewIntent(...)
2. starting a new activity and handling just onCreate()

If there is a performance issue, how big is the impact (on different devices)?

Comment: Do an experiment and tell the world. My bet is - unnoticeable

Comment: I did and I didn't notice any difference. However its a small app with no big magic. So question is, if other people with more sophisticated apps experienced the same thing.